# How do I create a partially transparent flag?

Tags: materials, transparency

I'm making an animation with a flag, and I was wondering if anyone knows how to create like a transparent fabric material?

The flag looks a bit dull, and doesn't look realistic at all. After some references I noticed that flags are a bit transparent, seeing as they are woven.

Reference :

[image]

I need to make this flag have the same type of material

If you can tell me how to make it look like fabric and not like rubber, I'd be very thankful.

P.S: If anybody knows how to make little "ripples", please comment and let me know.

Comment: Are you using Cycles?

Comment: What you are looking for is translucency.

Comment: I made a shader trying to imitate your reference image, but I noticed some problems with it after I rendered an example.. Is something like [this](http://gfycat.com/RecentScalyGenet) close to what you are looking for?

Comment: @gandalf3 hey, is it possible for you to share the shader with me? it's wonderful!!!

Comment: @Mikhail Viljoen did you find a solution?

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne [Here you go](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3452/) :) It's probably not really physically realistic, but perhaps you can adapt it

Answer (score 3):

Well this is not too straightforward, especially if you would like a very realistic result. For more realism I would recommend using [subsurface scattering](http://archive.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-244/subsurface-scattering/index.html) to achieve such an effect.
I suggest you start off with translucency as [GiantCowFilms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/3127/giantcowfilms) suggested. Here is a simple configuration that you can start with:

[image]

[(Image from Daccy, BlenderArtists)](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?243715-Cycles-semi-transparent-material)

PS: You would need a few separate passes (masks) as some of parts of that flag are more translucent than others and some are not at all...